# Setting an array value results in an Argument not optional error in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vba

I am trying to set the values of an array of Collections inside a For loop. However, when I go to run the program, it throws a compile error that states "Argument not optional" and highlights the part where I set the array value. When I go to debug the subroutine, I cannot get past the first line of ConvertbucketCollectionTobucketArray(). At that point, bucketArray elements 0 through 12 have a value of Nothing and bucketCollection contains 13 elements(1-13), where only several contain items.

```
Dim bucketCollection As New Collection 'the Collection of buckets
Dim bucketArray(12) As New Collection 'bucketCollection as an array
```

...

```
Private Sub ConvertbucketCollectionTobucketArray() 'debugger stops here

    Dim newCol As Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To bucketCollection.count

        Set newCol = bucketCollection.Item(i)
        bucketArray(i - 1) = newCol 'highlighted line here

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since collection is an object, you have to use set when copying it to an element (this is your error).

```
Set bucketArray(i - 1) = newCol
```

This will not cause an error, but an array doesn't need to be set as new.

```
Dim bucketArray(12) As Collection
```

And if bucketCollection is a classwide variable, you should separate creating a new instance and declaring it. Create a new instance of it in one of the functions. Otherwise, if you run the same code twice, it might use the same instance.

```
Sub test()
    Set bucketCollection = New Collection
    populate
    ConvertbucketCollectionTobucketArray
End Sub
```